# How to pipe to a program in the same directory as a Bash script on macOS?

Tags: bash, macos

I've written a Bash script that's meant to delete a file then run `sqlite3`. It runs fine in my mingw64 Bash on Windows, but fails in Bash on macOS.

My script comes with its own copy of `sqlite3` in the same directory as the script.

```
rm -f Input.sqlite
cat SqliteCommands.txt | sqlite3
```

Output:

> compy:program me$ ./Run-Bash.sh
>   : command not found 2: sqlite3
>   cat: SqliteCommands.txt: No such file or directory

I remembered that to run a program in the current directory you need to prefix it with `./`, so I changed it to:

```
cat SqliteCommands.txt | ./sqlite3
```

...which weirdly gets me this error output (verbatim). I don't know why it removed the "sql" part of the file name, that's weird.

> : No such file or directorylite3
>   cat: SqliteCommands.txt: No such file or directory

As macOS comes with its own copy of `sqlite3` I changed it to use the full path, but as macOS comes with an older version it means I had to change my `SqliteCommands.txt` to be compatible which isn't ideal.

```
cat SqliteCommands.txt | /usr/bin/sqlite3
```

So how can I pipe to an executable in the same directory as the script?

Comment: What is the output of `file sqlite3`?

Comment: `Run-Bash.sh` contains a DOS carriage return. Don't use Windows, use a proper editor. `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\015' <Run-Bash.sh` to fix.

Comment: And completely tangentially, avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure, but try this:

```
sqlite3 "$(cat SqliteCommands.txt)"
```

or

```
cat SqliteCommands.txt | xargs -I {} sqlite3 {}
```